How define \eqset as \eqdef is defined (stix)
I use stix and in this package when I write $\eqdef$, an equal-symbol with an overwritten $\text{def}$ appears. I'd like to create \newcommand{\eqset}{...} in the same way that \eqdef is defined.
Is it possible?
Thank you so much.

Here's a solution that uses the TeX primitives \ooalign, \kern, \raise, \hbox, and \cr.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stix}
\newcommand\myeqdef{\mathrel{\ooalign{\kern0.11pt\raise1.02ex\hbox{\tiny def}\cr$=$}}}
\newcommand\myeqset{\mathrel{\ooalign{\kern0.55pt\raise1.02ex\hbox{\tiny set}\cr$=$}}}

\begin{document}
$u\eqdef v$

$u\myeqdef v$ 

$u\myeqset v$
\end{document}


Why \ooalign?

@egreg - I suppose you've addressed your own question in the answer you've posted. :-) +1.

The right tool for this application is \ialign (which will stack objects), rather than \ooalign (that's designed to superimpose symbols).
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stix}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\genericeq}[1]{% use only in text or display style
  \mathrel{\vbox{\offinterlineskip
    \ialign{\hfil##\hfil\cr
      \normalfont\fontsize{\fpeval{\f@size*0.525}}{0}\selectfont #1\cr
      \noalign{\vspace{0.5pt}}
      $\m@th=$\cr
    }%
  }}%
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\eqset}{}{\genericeq{set}}

\begin{document}

$u\eqdef v$ versus $u\genericeq{def} v$

$u\eqset v$

\end{document}

In the first line there's \eqdef as defined by stix that you can compare with \genericeq{def}.


\eqdef is the unicode character U+225D ≝ so you can not make commands with different words in the same way, although you can use \stackrel{\mathrm{set}}{=}  or similar combinations with different font choice for set.
